# NTLM Windows authentication in WAS Liberty

Tags: websphere, windows-authentication, ntlm, websphere-liberty

I have a web application on Liberty that uses form-based authentication. Is there native support in Liberty to integrate NTLM-based Windows Authentication (Liberty version 8.5.5.6) ?

Answer (score 1):

The is no support for NTLM, but if you are looking for web based SSO with Windows, Liberty fully supports Kerberos/SPNEGO authentication.

For more details check [Configuring SPNEGO authentication in Liberty](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_spnego_config.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-4-2-8&lang=en)

Comment: Thanks, I came across the same link. For this configuration, it seems that you'll need access to the domain controller machine, which I don't have. Is there an alternate way for configuring the domain controller?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for NTLM-based Windows Authentication on Liberty that I know of, but Liberty can still utilize services that have NTLM support.

For example, configuring a DataSource that uses JDBC NTLM Authentication:

```
<dataSource id="NTLM-DataSource" jndiName="jdbc/NTLM-DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DataDirectLib"/>
    <properties databaseName="SAMPLEDB" 
                hostName="localhost" 
                port="12345"
                URL="jdbc:datadirect:sqlserver://localhost\SAMPLEDB;AuthenticationMethod=ntlm;DatabaseName=MyServer$SAMPLEDB"/>
</dataSource>

<library id="DataDirectLib">
    <fileset dir="C:/path/to/sqlserver.jar"/>
</library>
```

Sources:

- [Progress Blogs](https://www.progress.com/blogs/websphere-liberty-profile-jdbc-ntlm-windows-authentication-from-unix-linux-to-sql-server)
- [IBM DataSource config documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html)